# MySQL search TEXT field for matching text, for absolute on a multiline

Tags: mysql, innodb

Okay, I have a table in InnoDB. It has a column called "spellings" which is a TEXT field (not varchar). In this column, I have multiple ways to spell something, each way separated by a line break. For instance one of the rows is as follows:

```
Soulcalibur
Soul Calibur
```

Then I have another row with this information

```
Soulcalibur II
Soulcalibur 2
Soul Calibur II
Soul Calibur 2
```

Now lets say I want to find rows that contain "Soul Calibur", I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE spellings LIKE '%Soul Calibur%'
```

The problem with this is it returns BOTH rows, because technically the second row does have "Soul Calibur". Is there a way in a MySQL query to query for Soul Calibur that will only show fields that contain EXACTLY Soul Calibur on a line. Basically an exact match after parsing for the line breaks.

If I remove the %, it doesnt work because the first row is technically `Soulcalibur\nSoul Calibur`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to use char(10) for line breaks. So Try
 like CONCAT('%Soul Calibur', CHAR(10), '%')

Comment: Okay, this doesnt work. It will match `Soulcalibur`, but not `Soul Calibur`, since it does not have a line break after it since it is the end of the string.